# Facebook Ads tracking app installs without SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I have an app using the Facebook SDK.

However, the SDK is not setup to track app installs as described by Facebook, so the following is missing:

`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
   [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}`

Still, Facebook Ads is reporting app installs. Why?

Is it just because some users do login/signup with Facebook in the app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I believe this is the right explanation:

> The Facebook SDK for iOS automatically takes care of storing and fetching data on Facebook session management for your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/token-cache